# Rx Subscribe OnComplete fires but cannot use the data

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a product service with a method that returns an Observable from json data.

**product.service.ts....**

```
getProducts(): Observable<IProductData[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProductData[]> response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

In my component I subscribe to the serivce and call the getProducts() method returning the Observable IProductData[].

**mycomponent.ts ..**

```
productData: IProductData[];

ngOnInit(): void {

    this._productService.getProductsObservable()
        .subscribe(
                productData => this.productData = <IProductData[]>productData,
                error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error,
                function() { console.log(this.productData ) }
        );
}
```

When I review the **onCompleted** console.log **this.productData** is undefined!

I want to use this data to setup the fields in my component. When/how can I be sure that the data has been returned?

If I output **this.productData** on a button click event the data has been populated, but I want to do this on init.

Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using an arrow function in the final block so your `this` is local to the `complete` function that you pass in.

In addition to appearances there are actual semantic differences between `() => {}` and `function() {}`

Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

> ...Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value (a new object in case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the context object if the function is called as an "object method", etc.). This proved to be annoying with an object-oriented style of programming.
>
> In ECMAScript 3/5, this issue was fixed by assigning the value in this to a variable that could be closed over.
>
> An arrow function does not create its own this context; rather, it captures the this value of the enclosing context...

Comment: Thanks Paul that was it! I now have a much clearer understanding of how arrow functions work in JavaScript :)